# Clipping a raster with a buffer of road network in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, clip

I use QGIS 3.12 and trying to clip a raster by the buffer of a road network. Both the raster and the road network dataset are in the same reference system.
When I run the "Clip raster by mask layer", I get a black raster with no data.
I tried to run the same algorithm with another vector file (of a square area) and it works well. Is it possible to clip raster based on a complicated polygon?

[image]